# PHP script runs over Browser but not with wget

Tags: php, browser, wget, debian-based

I have a bash-sctipt running 5 php scripts via wget.
Every php file is called but, on the last script, I get this warning:

> mysql_query(): supplied argument is
>   not a valid MySQL-Link resource in
>   xyz.php, on line ABC

What it is really strange is, if I run the same script via browser, the script runs fine, without any warning.

This is my code near line ABC:

```
$sqlSTR="INSERT INTO accounts_cstm (id_c, mtk_categoriascompradas_c) VALUES ('". $arr[1] . "', '" . $arr[0] . "')
                    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE mtk_categoriascompradas_c= concat(mtk_categoriascompradas_c, '^,^$arr[0]')";        

$ExecuteSQL = mysql_query ($sqlSTR, $DBConn) or
                die ($sqlSTR); //warning on this line - line ABC
```

My SQL is totally valid (if I run the query that is outputed in the "die" statement it runs perfectly), the DBConn is connected to the database and all other scripts run fine, except this one.

I really don't know what is causing this *Warning*.
Any help will be welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Do you use the same URL in wget and in browser?

Comment: @Stephen: the array is fine. I checked that on the "die" output ($sqlSTR is totally valid)
@zilupe: the URL is exactly the same

Comment: @Armadillo: when you say the script runs fine in the browser, do you get the query echoed out? Because from your code it should only die when the query fails?

Comment: @BrynJ: No, the query is not echoed and the query is successfully executed (I cheked in the database)

Answer (score 4):

Your problem actually lies with your database connection (`$DBConn`). Take a look at that code. Stick a var_dump in and try wgetting again.

Comment: +1, yes the error does seem to point to an issue with the connection.

Comment: no sure, because I can run the script via browser, with exactly the same URL.

Comment: I'm not saying it for my own health. The error *means* the database connection isn't valid. You need to look at that part of the code if you want to find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Always use `mysql_error()` when you see this error message. Then you`ll know the exact reason, why the query was invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Something definitely looks wrong with your last reference to $arr[0] in the query - I think it needs to be the following:

```
$sqlSTR="INSERT INTO accounts_cstm (id_c, mtk_categoriascompradas_c) VALUES ('". $arr[1] . "', '" . $arr[0] . "')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE mtk_categoriascompradas_c= concat(mtk_categoriascompradas_c, '^,^".$arr[0]."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the URL you are calling with wget have an ampersand in it?  If you do, make sure your shell isn't interpreting it as a `send process to background`

Comment: The URL doesn't have any ampersand or any special character.

Comment: Okay.  I'm not familiar with how debian does php, but my ubuntu boxes have a different php.ini for command-line vs apache.  You might have a similar setup with the cli-php having a slightly different setup that is affecting your script.